# addition, subtraction, and comparison of large numbers of any base between 2 and 36

Tags: c

I need to put some additional code for subtraction and comparison.
and i put (bool larger) for comparison.

When i run this and input 1 '<' 2 to compare, it says "Invalid operation: < ".
and also for the 1 = 1, it says "Invalid operation: = ".
but the result need to be "Result: false" and "Result: True"

I have no idea about it. I know the code is long but not so complicated. Please get me some hint if you can.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bignum_math.h"


/*
 * Returns true if the given char is a digit from 0 to 9
 */
bool is_digit(char c) {
    return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
}

/*
 * Returns true if lower alphabetic character
 */
bool is_lower_alphabetic(char c) {
    return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z';
}

/*
 * Returns true if upper alphabetic character
 */
bool is_upper_alphabetic(char c) {
    return c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z';
}

/*
 * Convert a string to an integer
 * returns 0 if it cannot be converted.
 */
int string_to_integer(char* input) {
    int result = 0;
    int length = strlen(input);
    int num_digits = length;
    int sign = 1;

    int i = 0;
    int factor = 1;

    if (input[0] == '-') {
        num_digits--;
        sign = -1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_digits; i++, length--) {
        if (!is_digit(input[length-1])) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (i > 0) factor*=10;
        result += (input[length-1] - '0') * factor;
    }

    return sign * result;
}

/*
 * Returns true if the given base is valid.
 * that is: integers between 2 and 36
 */
bool valid_base(int base) {
    if(!(base >= 2 && base <= 36)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/*
 * TODO
 * Returns true if the given string (char array) is a valid input,
 * that is: digits 0-9, letters A-Z, a-z
 * and it should not violate the given base and should not handle negative numbers
 */
bool valid_input(char* input, int base) {
    /*
     * check for valid base and if negative
     */
    if (!valid_base(base) || input[0]=='-') {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        int len = strlen(input);
        int i;
        for (i =0; i< len; i++){
            /*
             * check if the input string is a digit/letter
             */
            if (!(is_digit(input[i]) || is_lower_alphabetic(input[i]) || is_upper_alphabetic(input[i]))){
                return false;
            }
            /*
             * if the int excesses the base?
             */
            else if (is_digit(input[i])){
                if (input[i]-'0'>=base){     //convert char to int and compare with the base
                    return false;
                }

            }
            /*
             *or if the letter excesses the base?
             */

            else if (is_lower_alphabetic(input[i])){
                if (input[i]-'a'+10 >=base){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (is_upper_alphabetic(input[i])){
                if (input[i] - 'A' + 10 >=base) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
}


/*
 * converts from an array of characters (string) to an array of integers
 */
int* string_to_integer_array(char* str) {
    int* result;
    int i, str_offset = 0;
    result = malloc((strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(int));
    result[strlen(str)] = -1;
    for(i = str_offset; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(is_digit(str[i])) {
            result[i - str_offset] = str[i] - '0';
        } else if (is_lower_alphabetic(str[i])) {
            result[i - str_offset] = str[i] - 'a' + 10;
        } else if (is_upper_alphabetic(str[i])) {
            result[i - str_offset] = str[i] - 'A' + 10;
        } else {
            printf("I don't know how got to this point!\n");
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/*
 * finds the length of a bignum...
 * simply traverses the bignum until a negative number is found.
 */
int bignum_length(int* num) {
    int len = 0;
    while(num[len] >= 0) { len++; }
    return len;
}

/*
 * TODO
 * Prints out a bignum using digits and upper-case characters
 * Current behavior: prints integers
 * Expected behavior: prints characters
 */
void bignum_print(int* num) {
    int i;
    if(num == NULL) { return; }

    /* Handle negative numbers as you want
     * let the last digit be -2 if negative
     * */
    i = bignum_length(num);
    if (num[i]==-2){
        printf("-");
    }

    /* Then, print each digit */
    for(i = 0; num[i] >= 0; i++) {
        if (num[i]<=9){
            printf("%d", num[i]);
        }
        else if (num[i]>9){
            char digit =  num[i]+'A'-10;
            printf("%c", digit);
        }

    }
    printf("\n");
}

/*
 *  Helper for reversing the result that we built backward.
 *  see add(...) below
 */
void reverse(int* num) {
    int i, len = bignum_length(num);
    for(i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {
        int temp = num[i];
        num[i] = num[len-i-1];
        num[len-i-1] = temp;
    }
}


/*
 * used to add two numbers with the same sign
 * GIVEN FOR GUIDANCE
 */
int* add(int* input1, int* input2, int base) {
    int len1 = bignum_length(input1);
    int len2 = bignum_length(input2);
    int resultlength = ((len1 > len2)? len1 : len2) + 2;
    int* result = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int) * resultlength);
    int r = 0;
    int carry = 0;
    int sign = input1[len1];

    len1--;
    len2--;

    while(len1 >= 0 || len2 >= 0) {
        int num1 = (len1 >= 0)? input1[len1] : 0;
        int num2 = (len2 >= 0)? input2[len2] : 0;
        result[r] = (num1 + num2 + carry) % base;
        carry = (num1 + num2 + carry) / base;
        len1--;
        len2--;
        r++;
    }
    if(carry > 0) { result[r] = carry; r++; }
    result[r] = sign;
    reverse(result);
    return result;
}

/*
 * helper function for subtract
 * determine which number is larger of two positive numbers
 */
bool larger(int* input1, int* input2){
    int len1 = bignum_length(input1);
    int len2 = bignum_length(input2);
    if (len1<=len2){
        if (len1<len2){  //if input1 has less digit than input2
            return false;
        }
        int i;
        for (i =0; i < len1; i++ ){//they have the same length
            if (input1[i]<input2[i]){    //if the same digit in input1 is smaller than that in input2
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;  //else input1 is indeed larger than/equal input2 (longer or every digit is no less than that in input2
}


/*
 * helper function for subtract
 * subtract from the larger
 */
int* subtractLarger(int* input1, int* input2, int base){  //input1 is larger or equal than/to input2 and both positive

    int len1 = bignum_length(input1);
    int len2 = bignum_length(input2);
    int resultlength = ((len1 > len2) ? len1 : len2) + 2;
    int *result = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * resultlength);
    int r = 0;
    int carry = 0;
    int sign = -1;

    len1--;
    len2--;
    while(len1 >= 0 ) {
        int num1 = (len1 >= 0)? input1[len1]-carry : 0;
        int num2 = (len2 >= 0)? input2[len2] : 0;
        if (num1>=num2){
            result[r] = (num1-num2);
            carry = 0;
        }
        else {
            result[r]= num1+base-num2;
            carry = 1;

        }

        len1--;
        len2--;
        r++;
    }
    if (result[r-1]==0){
        result[r-1] = sign;
    }
    else {
        result[r] = sign;
    }
    reverse(result);
    return result;
}



/*
 * used to subtract two numbers with the same sign
 */
int* subtract (int* input1, int* input2, int base) {
    if (larger(input1,input2)){
        return subtractLarger(input1, input2, base);
    }
    else {
        int* res = subtractLarger(input2, input1, base);  //exchange input1 and input2, note the result is negative
        int sign = -2;                                    //negative result
        res[bignum_length(res)] = sign;
        return res;
    }
}
/*
 * TODO
 * This function is where you will write the code that performs the heavy lifting,
 * actually performing the calculations on input1 and input2.
 * Return your result as an array of integers.
 * HINT: For better code structure, use helper functions.
 */
int* perform_math(int* input1, int* input2, char op, int base) {

    /*
     * this code initializes result to be large enough to hold all necessary digits.
     * if you don't use all of its digits, just put a -1 at the end of the number.
     * you may omit this result array and create your own.
     */

    int resultlength = bignum_length(input1) + bignum_length(input2) + 2;
    int* result = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int) * resultlength);

    if(op == '+') {
        return add(input1, input2, base);
    }
    else if (op == '-'){
        return subtract(input1, input2, base);

    }

}


/*
 * Print to "stderr" and exit program
 */
void print_usage(char* name) {
    fprintf(stderr, "----------------------------------------------------\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s base input1 operation input2\n", name);
    fprintf(stderr, "base must be number between 2 and 36, inclusive\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "input1 and input2 are arbitrary-length integers\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Two operations are allowed '+' and '-'\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "----------------------------------------------------\n");
    exit(1);
}


/*
 * MAIN: Run the program and tests your functions.
 * sample command: ./bignum 4 12 + 13
 * Result: 31
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int input_base;

    int* input1;
    int* input2;
    int* result;

    if(argc != 5) { 
        print_usage(argv[0]); 
    }

    input_base = string_to_integer(argv[1]);

    if(!valid_base(input_base)) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid base: %s\n", argv[1]);
        print_usage(argv[0]);
    }


    if(!valid_input(argv[2], input_base)) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input1: %s\n", argv[2]);
        print_usage(argv[0]);
    }

    if(!valid_input(argv[4], input_base)) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input2: %s\n", argv[4]);
        print_usage(argv[0]);
    }

    if(argv[3][0] != '-' && argv[3][0] != '+') {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid operation: %s\n", argv[3]);
        print_usage(argv[0]);
    }

    input1 = string_to_integer_array(argv[2]);
    input2 = string_to_integer_array(argv[4]);

    result = perform_math(input1, input2, argv[3][0], input_base);

    printf("Result: ");
    bignum_print(result);

    printf("\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 344:

```
void print_usage(char* name) {
    fprintf(stderr, "----------------------------------------------------\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s base input1 operation input2\n", name);
    fprintf(stderr, "base must be number between 2 and 36, inclusive\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "input1 and input2 are arbitrary-length integers\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Two operations are allowed '+' and '-'\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "----------------------------------------------------\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Line 390:

```
if(argv[3][0] != '-' && argv[3][0] != '+') {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid operation: %s\n", argv[3]);
    print_usage(argv[0]);
}
```

Now guess why it says "Invalid operation:"...